# how to use one sonar server on multiple machines

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I am using Java,Eclipse.I have installed & configured sonar-server,sonar-runner on my machine,it is working properly.I have tested the code quality of my project on my machine using `http://localhost:9000/`. Everything is working fine.But now I want to test code quality of project which is on another machine using sonar server which is on my machine.(Means I have 5 machines then I don't want to install sonar-server,sonar-runner on all machines, I just  installed it on one machine & want to use it for all other machines).

How to connect sonar server to the project which is on another or different machine.
Please guide me,how to do this?How to do setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On all your other machines, you need to install the Sonar Runner and configure it to point to your remote Sonar server. To do so: edit the "conf/sonar-runner.properties" file to reference the URL of your remote Sonar server and the JDBC connection to your remote database.

All this is explained here: [Installing and Configuring Sonar Scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)