# Is it possible to run an On premise SonarQube Server on azure devops deploy pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I'm deploying my application to an on promise IIS server and I would like to run a sonarQube Analytics at the same time, using a self-hosted agent, but the sonarQube server is in another server.

I was thinking to run a command using cmd to start the analytics, but I'm not sure how to do this because sonarQube is in another server.

Comment: Did you look at the SonarQube documentation? You should be able to find tons of resource with a little bit of Googling.

Comment: Actually I googled more than a little bit, but I couldn't find anything that helped me, that's why I'm here. Could you please share what you had found with me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to run an On premise SonarQube Server on azure devops deploy pipeline?

The short answer is yes.

You don't need SonarQube to be hosted on same server. You can use SonarScanner as client on your build server and the scanner will push data to SonarQube.

There is an image about [SonarQube Architecture and Integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/architecture/architecture-integration/):

[image]

obviously, SonarQube Scanner should be what you are looking for.

Read more about SonarScanner here:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/

Certificate from: [how to use one sonar server on multiple machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927868/how-to-use-one-sonar-server-on-multiple-machines).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it'll surely help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your server. The main condition is availability of your SonarQube server from internet because Azure DevOps creates a service connection. You can find lessons here: [Managing technical debt with SonarQube and Azure DevOps](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/)